# Negligible at extreme

Tags: adjectives

Can *negligible* be used to describe something which has no significance at all?

For example, would the condition "we will ignore this requirement if the decimal value is negligible" also apply to the case where the decimal value is 0.0? The intention is to ignore the requirement in the case of 0.0.

So is this usage OK, is this usage too ambiguous, or would using it this way expressly imply it cannot be zero?

Comment: The etymology is straightforward: _neglect_ + _-able_ (though in Latin, not English). This is something you can neglect with impunity.

Comment: Are you saying the etymology of negligible is the word neglectable or the same as the word neglectable?

Comment: Yes. It's how they said it in Latin. With the same meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/negligible) has for *negligible,* "So small or unimportant as to be not worth considering; insignificant."

For something to be negligible, there must be something to disregard. It's akin to *de minimis:* something to which a rule would apply, but it's so trivial it's an exception. But there is still something to consider as not reaching the threshold.

If the decimal value is zero, is there anything to consider at all?

Perhaps a better way of putting it is to turn it round: "We will only consider this requirement if the decimal value is not negligible." It's then up to you to decide at what value it becomes important. Anything lower than that threshold (including zero) is negligible.

However, if you really mean *not zero* and any non-zero value cannot be ignored, then say that: "We will ignore this requirement if the decimal value is zero."

Comment: Contrapositive, good solution! Thank you. Interestingly, while I do only care about the value being zero, it isn't actually a decimal but a floating-point value, so it is unsafe to guarantee there won't be any rounding errors in practice, therefor there has to be a threshold for negligibility when comparing it to zero. JH